# enabling sql trace for a binary executable

Tags: sql, oracle, trace

I have an executable that connects to Oracle and executes some sql. I want to enable tracing for this executable. Usually we put alter session sstatement to enable trace but the session is created inside the executable. How to enable trace for this?

Comment: can you change what the executable does?  or is it closed / pre-compiled?

Comment: Does the application run the SQL immediately, or is there a gap between connecting to the DB and running it, during which you could turn on session-level tracing [via `DBMS_MONITOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/sqltrace.htm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one option if you cannot change the executable / its calling SQL is to create a logon trigger that sets tracing on. Then have the executable connect to the db and it should start tracing out.